# Transpose rows to columns based on ID column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm currently running SQL Server 2008 and trying to get the following subquery data:

```
ID | Field Name | Field Selection
1  |  Rating 1  |      Good
1  |  Rating 2  |      Good
1  |  Rating 3  |      Bad
2  |  Rating 1  |      OK
```

Grouped into a single row based on the ID column:

```
ID | Rating 1 | Rating 2 | Rating 3
1  |    Good  |    Good  |   Bad
2  |     OK   |    NULL  |   NULL
```

Is this possible? Thanks in advance!

Cheers,
Si

Comment: Since you're using SQL Server (Yay!), look at the [PIVOT](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx) operator (2005+). Have fun! (Any solution that does not require dynamic SQL or some procedural code will be limited to a *fixed set* of output columns that must be specified in the query.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use SQL Server pivot clause for this:

```
select
    p.*
from Table1
pivot(
    max([Field Selection])
    for [Field Name] in ([Rating 1], [Rating 2], [Rating 3])
) as p
```

or you can pivot manually:

```
select
    ID,
    max(case when [Field Name] = 'Rating 1' then [Field Selection] end) as [Rating 1], 
    max(case when [Field Name] = 'Rating 2' then [Field Selection] end) as [Rating 2],
    max(case when [Field Name] = 'Rating 3' then [Field Selection] end) as [Rating 3]
from Table1
group by ID
```

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f5110/3)</kbd>**

Comment: Hi Roman,
Thanks for your suggestion. I'm currently receiving "Operand data type ntext is invalid for max operator". Just to clarify the Field Name and Selection columns are text and not ID's.

Comment: Absolute legend! Casting it as an nvarchar in the sub sorted it.