# SQL combine rows based on an ID?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that has multiple rows of data that I need to combine.

Table

```
Name    ColumnName  ID  Value
T1        Time      1   2:00 PM
T1        Time      2   3:00 PM
T1        Date      1   1/29/18
T1        Date      2   1/30/18
T1        Text      1   Apple
T1        Text      2   Orange
T1        Start     1   10:00 AM
T1        Start     2   8:00 AM
```

From this data I would like to get rows like this that are each based on the ID:

```
Name  Time    Date     Text    Start
T1    2:00PM  1/29/18  Apple   10:00AM
T1    3:00PM  1/30/18  Orange  8:00AM
```

Would this be something that needs to be pivoted?

Comment: What happens when you try using PIVOT?   What attempt did you make to research this question before posting?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Transpose rows to columns based on ID column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19714304/transpose-rows-to-columns-based-on-id-column)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select name,
       max(case when columnname = 'time' then value end) as time,
       max(case when columnname = 'Date' then value end) as Date,
       max(case when columnname = 'text' then value end) as text,
       max(case when columnname = 'Start' then value end) as Start
from t
group by name;
```

Comment: Close to correct. You'd be grouping by ID, not be Name. Also make sure to cast/convert to the appropriate type if that's what you want.

Comment: This works great. Thank you, I didn't really know how to start with this one.